# How can this repetitive code be simplified?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, objectlistview

The following code is very repetitive, but contains very slight differences in what properties are accessed. They change between RMs/FMs/FEs and PrimaryRM/PrimaryFM/PrimaryFE depending on which column the `GroupKeyGetter` applies to.

I can't find a way of converting this into a method so that I do not need to have this massive block of code, but there has to be a way of doing this in a better way...

```
allRMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate(object rowObject)
{
    var users = ((Tenant) rowObject).RMs.Trim().Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return users.FirstOrDefault(user => GlobalSettings.Users.Find(x => x.Name == user && x.Selected) != null) ?? ((Tenant)rowObject).PrimaryRM;
};

allFMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate (object rowObject)
{
    var users = ((Tenant)rowObject).FMs.Trim().Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return users.FirstOrDefault(user => GlobalSettings.Users.Find(x => x.Name == user && x.Selected) != null) ?? ((Tenant)rowObject).PrimaryFM;
};

allFEsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate (object rowObject)
{
    var users = ((Tenant)rowObject).FEs.Trim().Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return users.FirstOrDefault(user => GlobalSettings.Users.Find(x => x.Name == user && x.Selected) != null) ?? ((Tenant) rowObject).PrimaryFE;
};
```

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Is there a common type between `RMs`, `FMs`, and `FEs`?

Comment: @DStanley They're all strings, same as `PrimaryRM`, `PrimaryFM`, `PrimaryFE`

Comment: Should have guessed that from the `Trim()` call.  Thanks.  BTW 9 lines of code (excluding whitespace and punctuation) is not "massive" by any means.  You can improve reuse but I doubt you can get it to fewer _lines_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make helper methods for extracting selected `User`, like this:

```
private string GetFirstSelectedUser(string userList) {
    var users = userList.Trim().Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return users.FirstOrDefault(user => GlobalSettings.Users.Find(x => x.Name == user && x.Selected) != null);
}
```

Now all three delegates could be coded like this:

```
allRMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    var renant = (Tenant) rowObject;
    return GetFirstSelectedUser(tenant.RMs) ?? tenant.PrimaryRM;
};
```

If you are free to make restructuring to the `Tenant` and can group `FEs` with `PrimaryFE`, `FMs` with `PrimaryFM`, and `RMs` with `PrimaryRM`, you could simplify your method even further:

```
class GroupWithPrimary {
    public string Group {get;}
    public string Primary {get;}
    public GroupWithPrimary(string group, string primary) {
        Group = group;
        Primary = primary;
    }
}
private string GetFirstSelectedUser(GroupWithPrimary gp) {
    var users = gp.Group.Trim().Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return users.FirstOrDefault(user => GlobalSettings.Users.Find(x => x.Name == user && x.Selected) != null) ?? gp.Primary
}
allRMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    return GetFirstSelectedUser(((Tenant)rowObject).RM);
};
allFMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    return GetFirstSelectedUser(((Tenant)rowObject).FM);
};
allFEsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    return GetFirstSelectedUser(((Tenant)rowObject).FE);
};
```

Comment: Granted that's a bit smaller on each delegate, but I find it doesn't exactly simplify the code. The number of lines actually goes up a bit. Isn't there a way of just passing the whole thing off to a method?

Comment: @JohnUbuntu This approach pushed the logic that you repeated three times into a sinle method. You could pass default value as well if you wish, to push the `??` into the method as well, but that does not change much. All the logic is in one place now, no repetition. If you could group your `RMs`+`PrimaryRM`, `FEs`+`PrimaryFE` etc. into a class, then you would be able to simplify the method further.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu So what's your criteria for "simpler"?  There's no repeated code, so in MY mind it's simpler.  Fewer lines of code is not always better.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: it is simpler in that there's no repeated code, but I was hoping to be able to simplify it further. I guess I was just a bit disappointed at not being able to further simplify it.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it moves all of the repeated code into a method and simplifies the code. Accepted answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the difference between the three variants can be extracted into to funcs, like so:

```
Func<object, object> CreateGroupKeyGetter(Func<Tenant, string> func1, 
           Func<Tenant, string> func2)
{
    return rowObject=>
            {
                var users = func1(((Tenant) rowObject)).Trim().Split(new[] ", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                return users.FirstOrDefault(user => GlobalSettings.Users.Find(x => x.Name == user && x.Selected) != null) ?? func2(((Tenant)rowObject));
            }
}

allRMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = CreateGroupKeyGetter(t=>t.Rms, t=>t.PrimaryRm);
allFMsColumn.GroupKeyGetter = CreateGroupKeyGetter(t=>t.Fms, t=>t.PrimaryFm);
allFesColumn.GroupKeyGetter = CreateGroupKeyGetter(t=>t.Fes, t=>t.PrimaryFe);



}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. There's something wrong with the funcs and the `GroupKeyGetter` complains about not being able to convert to `GroupKeyGetterDelegate`. Like the idea though.

Comment: What;s the definition of `GroupKeyGetterDelegate`?

Comment: Well, there's no way for me to get the exact signature of the GroupKeyGetterDelegate, but you should be able to fix any type problems. Just wanted to give you an example of how to use higher order functions. Vote me up if you like it :)

Comment: @DStanley, @MikaelNitell `public delegate object GroupKeyGetterDelegate(object rowObject);`

Comment: OK, I edited the code sample to say Func<object, object>. That should work.